# Golang type assertion / cast to intermediate struct

Tags: go, go-interface

Given the following types:

```
type Event interface{}

type ActionResultEvent struct {
    Result string
}

type ActionSuccessEvent ActionResultEvent
type ActionFailureEvent ActionResultEvent

type eventHandleFunc func(e Event)
```

My goal is to have event handlers (of type `eventHandleFunc`) for the concrete types `ActionSuccessEvent`, `ActionFailureEvent`, as well as for the more abstract `ActionResultEvent`. The latter I would like to use for both `ActionSuccessEvent`s and `ActionFailureEvent`s.

Now my idea was to just type cast the `Event` interface to the structure I would like to work on and that works nicely for the concrete types.

```
// Working perfectly fine
func(e Event) {
  event := e.(ActionFailureEvent)
  fmt.Println(event.Result)
} (ActionFailureEvent{ Result: "failure" })

func(e Event) {
  event := e.(ActionSuccessEvent)
  fmt.Println(event.Result)
} (ActionSuccessEvent{ Result: "success" })
```

Now what about handlers accepting `ActionResultEvent`s? My absolute favourite would look like this one:

```
func(e Event) {
  event := e.(ActionResultEvent)
  fmt.Println(event.Result)
} (ActionSuccessEvent{ Result: "success" })
```

This obviously panics as `e` was of type `ActionSuccessEvent`.

Then we can of course cast to the initial type and back to intermediate:

```
// Works but would that would need to change whenever new types "extending" 
// ActionResultEvent are added
func(e Event) {
  var resultEvent ActionResultEvent

  switch e.(type) {
  case ActionSuccessEvent:
    resultEvent = ActionResultEvent(e.(ActionSuccessEvent))

  case ActionFailureEvent:
    resultEvent = ActionResultEvent(e.(ActionFailureEvent))
  }
  fmt.Println(resultEvent.Result)
} (ActionSuccessEvent{ Result: "success" })
```

Another really nice approach from my point would be:

```
// Error: use of e.(type) outside type switch
func(e Event) {
  resultEvent := ActionResultEvent(e.(type))
} (ActionSuccessEvent{ Result: "success" })
```

Can anybody think of a smooth solution? One side note: I am happy if the handler panics during runtime whenever a typecast fails, as the wrapper will recover from that.

This is the example code above on the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/yfXyYQWBCGU). Thanks!

Comment: "a smooth solution": Remodel. You cannot have smooth traditional OOP in Go. Try modeling it as interface types and compose them.

Comment: Ok, don't really get the down vote but hey. Would you have any examples or resources that might point me in the right direction?

Comment: I probably have to rephrase this: I am not looking for a solution to make the code above work. I am actually trying to understand how to address this general problem in a "go way"

Comment: Go doesn't have generics. [Do this instead.](https://appliedgo.net/generics/)

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for your comment, very interesting article. I found a solution using interfaces and interface composition.

Answer (score 1):

Although I got down votes here, I believe this could be of interest to others. So I decided to post the solution to what I have figured out to work: See the [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/EbSRPX41c2p)

If this is bad practice or not "the go way" of doing things I would be really happy to get some feedback. Thanks!